# How to make Ubuntu look like Windows 95

Tags: windows, themes

I want a replica rather than a theme if possible.

Windows 2000 or ME themes are fine too.

Comment: What about XP Themes?

Comment: What is a replica ??? I really have no idea what "replica rather than a theme" is, as the theme IS the look of the OS.

Comment: This may not be what you're looking for, but you might be interested in http://www.reactos.org/ , which is more of a "replica" of Windows than any version of Ubuntu will ever be.

Answer (score 5):

You can customize the look of ubuntu with themes,

so you could install a theme like [this](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Classic95+?content=158836) and some [icons](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Classic95?content=157298) and it should look pretty close to windows 95!

[image]

To install:

1. Install http://ubuntu-tweak.com/ .
2. Download and extract the theme into your .themes and .icons folders respectivly (found in your home directory press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files.)
3. Launch the tweak tools program, and go to "Tweaks" and click on theme.
4. From there select the theme you want!

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Good find but... How to install it? How to apply it? How about a nice screenshot so people can see it at a glance? As it stands this is boarder line a comment or `link only` flag, but with these improvements +1.

Comment: @markkirby done.

Comment: Nice, that should get some upvotes :) Only one small thing but it is really for others who read this, I would choose `unity-tweak-tool` over `ubuntu-tweak` as `unity-tweak-tool` is in the repos and does not require a 3rd party PPA to install or update, just `apt-get`, but that's just my preference.

Comment: how do you get the desktop and stuff?

Comment: @SmashNetwork In the discriptions on gnome-look it say you need  the mate desktop http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/install-mate-desktop-ubuntu-14-04-lts